# Measure the link speed of all scanned networks in Android

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is measure the link speed of each scanned network that [WiFiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) finds.

I retrieve all of the [scanned networks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) in a callback after `wifiManager.startScan();` has being called using the method `wifiManager.getScanResults();` but I can't find a method to measure the link speed of each scanned network.

The only way I could retrieve the link speed of a network is through [WifiInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html), but that object only represents the current Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: How do you propose Android should find the link speed of a network without connecting to it?

Comment: No idea. If that's the case, then my programming assignment is invalid. :)

Comment: Your hardware can read some information, i.e. SSID, without connecting.  Why not link speed?

Comment: The android device is not connected to a particular network. It just scanned all of the available networks. I want to retrieve the link speed of each scanned network. I can't figure out a way/hack.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19155133/1253844 for some relevant information.